# C++ Find Function Compile Error With std::string

Tags: c++, string, find

I've been reading Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" to learn how to program in C++, but the following example code from the text book doesn't seem to compile correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
 std::string s = "Hello!";
 char c = 'l';
 std::cout << "The number of " << c << "\'s in the string " << s << " is " << count(s,c);
}

int count(const std::string& s, char c)
{
    std::string::const_iterator i = std::string::find(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
    int n = 0;
    while(i != s.end())
    {
        ++n;
        i = std::find(i+1, s.end(), c);
    }

    return n;
}
```

These are the compile errors:

```
main.cpp:8:92: error: ‘count’ was not declared in this scope
      std::cout << "The number of " << c << "\'s in the string " << s << " is " << count(s,c);
                                                                                            ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int count(const string&, char)’:
main.cpp:13:80: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::find(std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, char&)’
         std::string::const_iterator i = std::string::find(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error tells you that when the compiler reaches `main`, it doesn't see any declaration for symbol `count`. This is one of the oddities of C and C++. To fix it, move the definition of `count` up, or merely declare its prototype before `main`.

The second error arises because you call the wrong function. From the arguments passed in, I guess you mean `std::find` rather than `std::string::find`. To get `std::find`, you also have to include the header `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Also needed is `#include <string>`

Answer (score 2):

`count` method is defined after `main`, so it is not visible in `main`. Either you have to *define* it before `main`, or you can *forward declare* `count`

```
int count(const std::string& s, char c) ;//forward declaration

int main()
{

  //code
}

int count(const std::string& s, char c)
{
 //code
}
```